# Explanation of uniqueness of square root

Tags: analysis

Let $c$ be a positive number. Then there is a unique positive number whose square is $c$. That is, $x^2=c$

Start:

- Suppose $a$ and $b$ are numbers whose square is $c$.
- then $a^2=c$ and $b^2=c$
- $c-c=0 = a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$

We know $(a+b) > 0$ because $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers.  For some reason my textbook concludes $a=b$ and thus the positive number whose square is $c$ is unique.  I'm not seeing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a+b>0$, it is particularly *not* zero. The only way for a product of two reals to give zero is if at least one of them is zero. Since $a+b\neq 0$, but $0 = (a-b)(a+b)$, it must be the case that $a-b=0$, i.e. $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a+b \neq 0$ we can multiply $(a-b)(a+b)  =0$ across by ${1 \over a+b}$ to
get $a-b=0$, that is, $a=b$.