# Proving the uniqueness of x=sqrt(r)

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, real-numbers, radicals

Given any $r \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, the number $\sqrt{r}$ is unique in the sense that, if $x$ is a positive real number such that $x^2 = r$, then $x = \sqrt{r}$

I would appreciate any nudge in the right direction. My initial thought would be to prove that this is impossible for $x<\sqrt{r}$ and $x>\sqrt{r}$.

Comment: You might like to see this page: [Explanation of uniqueness of square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122823/explanation-of-uniqueness-of-square-root).

Comment: The approach most in line with your initial thought is to consider that $x \mapsto x^2$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Comment: Can you show that $x\mapsto x^2$ is increasing on $\Bbb R_{>0}$?

Comment: If $x^2 = y^2 = r$ with $x,y>0$, then $(x+y)(x-y) = x^2-y^2 = 0$. As $x+y > 0$, we must have that $x-y=0$, i.e., $x = y$.

Comment: @amsmath Thank you, your comment cleared things up for me.